# Match a string from file and append it to another file

Tags: regex, powershell

Can anyone explain how the grouping work in this case. Because I dont understand.

The raw HTML that I'm matching against

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" >
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><font size=4></font></p>
<P></p>
<P></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
    Mesure </font>
    </td>
    <td>
    853.63
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Date and time
    </td>
    <td>
    2020/06/10 13:41:52
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    Text
    </td>
    <td>
    <font COLOR="BLACK">OTVOREN</font><font COLOR="RED"></font>
</tr>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

The powershell code:

```
$regex = @"
<tr>
<td>
Mesure </font>
</td>
<td>
(([0-9]*[ ])?([0-9]*[,\.])?[0-9]+)\s*
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Date and time
</td>
<td>
(([0-9]*[/,:]])?([0-9]*[/,:])?([0-9]*[/,:])?([0-9]*)?(\s*)?([0-9]*[:][0-9]*[:][0-9]*))
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Text
</td>
<td>
<font COLOR="BLACK">([A-Z])*</font><font COLOR="([A-Z])*"></font>
</tr>
"@


    $string = Get-Content $input_path -Encoding UTF8| Out-String |
    Select-String $regex -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1,4,3].Value } 


$a,$b,$c = $string.split('\n')
$a+ ',' + $b + ',' + $c  | Out-File $output_file -Encoding UTF8 -Append | Out-Null
```

The first strig is for example:

"853.63" and the regex for this is:

```
(([0-9]*[ ])?([0-9]*[,\.])?[0-9]+)\s*
```

Second string is "2020/06/10  13:41:52":

```
(([0-9]*[/,:]])?([0-9]*[/,:])?([0-9]*[/,:])?([0-9]*)?(\s*)?([0-9]*[:][0-9]*[:][0-9]*))
```

3d string is "OTVOREN":

```
([A-Z])*
```

and 4 is "RED":

```
([A-Z])*
```

They are in to the example on the top.

So I want to get this strings and append them in a file with "," separator. For example:

```
853.63,2020/06/10  13:41:52,OTVOREN,RED
854.00,2020/06/10  13:41:52,ZATVOREN,BLUE
...
```

At this point I acomplish to get the strings to the second one:
853.63,2020/06/10  13:41:52,

So why 1st string is in Group 1, 2nd is on Group 4(after 4 attempts :))? The other two I can't get them because don't know the number groups...

SOLVED:
 I made a mistake in the 3th regex ([A-Z])* instead ([A-Z]*). That brings it in Group 11.

Comment: Please post a sample string with which these results can be reproduced :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I posted the example strings each with the regex that I used in the example code.

Comment: No, I meant the input - the raw HTML you're matching against

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why 1st string is in Group 1, 2nd is on Group 4(after 4 attempts :))?

Because you've got nested capture groups in your pattern. Let's look at the first top-level group:

```
             Group 1
 ________________________________
/                                \
(([0-9]*[ ])?([0-9]*[,\.])?[0-9]+)
 \_________/ \___________/
   Group 2      Group 3
```

This can be observed by using the `$matches` variable:

```bsh
PS C:\> $null = '123 456.78' -match '(([0-9]*[ ])?([0-9]*[,\.])?[0-9]+)'
PS C:\> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
3                              456.
2                              123
1                              123 456.78
0                              123 456.78
```

Comment: Ok, so second string is in Group 4 that have 6 nested groups. So 4+6=10 and thats means I need to use Group 11 for the  3th  string. But the result is "N"

Comment: @HristianYordanov I strongly suggest you use the `$matches` trick to "see for yourself" :)

Comment: Yes I used it the second string have 7 groups in regex like the first comment. But still not working...

Comment: The 3th string has 2 Groups 0 is "OTVOREN" and Group 1 "N". When I use Group 11, N upears so I need to substract 1 Group. I use then Group 10 and the result is "13:41:52". There is no group for "OTVOREN" ?

Comment: I made a mistake in the 3th regex `([A-Z])*` instead `([A-Z]*)`. Group 11 now working. Thanks for `$matches` trick. Before that I used https://regexr.com/ to count the groups